# about Aggregation Pipeline Operator of mongodb($slice (aggregation))

Tags: python, mongodb

I want to use mongodb and python to deal with some data, the code is like this:

```
    pipeline = [
    {'$match':{'time':'03.02'}},
    {'$group':{'_id':{'$slice':['$address',1]},'counts':{'$sum':1}}},
    {'$sort':{'counts':-1}}
]

    for i in item_info.aggregate(pipeline):
        print i
```

but there are some errors like this:

> OperationFailure: command SON([('aggregate', u'item_info_3'), ('pipeline', [{'$match': {'$and': [{'pub_date': {'$lte': '12.27', '$gte': '12.25'}}, {'area': {'$all': ['\xe6\x9c\x9d\xe9\x98\xb3']}}]}}, {'$group': {'counts': {'$sum': 1}, '_id': {'$slice': ['$address', 2, 1]}}}, {'$limit': 3}]), ('cursor', {})]) on namespace GanjiData.$cmd failed: exception: invalid operator '$slice'

I really can't solve this problem,the mongodb version is 3.2.4

Comment: I'd suggest you to update your post along with sample documents. Also explain what are you trying to do?

Comment: The error would in fact indicate that the version is **not** a 3.2.x series release. I would suggest you have either installed a different version than you think or are connecting to a different instance than you think. Add to your code from the [database](https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/database.html) object as `db`: `db.command("buildinfo")['version']` which will return the actual server version of the instance you are connected to. FYI, You also probably really want `$arrayElemAt` since `$slice` will still return an array, and not just the element.